# My toilet has a weak flush

Tags: plumbing, toilet

When I flush my toilet the flush is rather weak and doesn't remove the contents of the bowl.   After the flush the water in the bowl drops to a low level.   If I dump additional water in the bowl it just goes down the drain.   I've checked the tank and everything seems fine.  I've tried plunging the toilet and snaking it as well with no success. Any help would be appreciated.   Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: With a small mirror check the holes under the toilet rim, they might be blocked and need cleaning.

Comment: Is it a newer toilet?   Some models have a inner reservoir where you press once on the handle for number one and press and hold the handle for number two.

Answer (score 1):

Take a bucket and fill it with around a gallon and 1/2 of water.
Pour it quickly into the toilet bowl.
If it flushes fine the issue is with the water flow from your tank to the bowl.

The water outlets in the bowl could be clogged and need to be cleaned. They are located under the rim of the bowl. A hard water deposit cleaner can be used to clean them. If this is the case you might want to clean your shower head as well if you have noticed lower water pressure while you take a shower!

The flapper inside the tank could be water logged and not staying afloat long enough for a good amount of water to travel from the tank to the bowl, or the chain, if it has one, could be too long. If you continue to hold the handle down, which holds the flapper up, and you get a strong flush then the flapper is most likely the issue. These are cheap to purchase and easy enough to change out.

FYI The flapper is the rubber piece that raises up to allow the water to flow out of the tank into the bowl.
The following illustration is from this website: https://toiletology.com/how-a-flush-toilet-works/

[image: diagram of the inside of a toilet tank]

This is old style but it lets you know where the flapper is. Disclaimer: I do not agree with all of the information on their site.